# Error with node-redis: Deprecated: The SET command contains a argument of type Object

Tags: json, node.js, encryption, redis

I'm using the `connect-redis-crypto` module (https://github.com/jas-/connect-redis-crypto
) which is built for encrypting redis session data on top of `connect-redis`(https://github.com/tj/connect-redis). My redis version is `3.2.8`.

I am running into error `node-redis: Deprecated: The SET command contains a argument of type Object`. Based on the larger error message, it seems to come from trying to parse the string `[object Object]` when it is not a JSON string. I put nested objects that hold user information on `req.session` which directly gets stored (and ideally encrypted) in redis.

From some sources I learned nested objects in Redis are not allowed which might cause this error, but I believe this library stores data as JSON to allow for nested objects. `connect-redis` works fine for me, but when this `connect-redis-crypto` library tries to JSON parse encrypted data it throws me this particular error.

Would really appreciate your help!

```js
node_redis: Deprecated: The SET command contains a argument of type Object.
This is converted to "[object Object]" by using .toString() now and will return an error from v.3.0 on.
Please handle this in your code to make sure everything works as you intended it to.
8 May 18:24:48 - ---NEW REQUEST---
REQUEST : GET /api/somePath/client
QUERY   : {}
BODY    : {}
data [object Object]
err SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Command.callback (/Users/Documents/web-AOT/server/node_modules/connect-redis-crypto/lib/connect-redis.js:262:35)
    at normal_reply (/Users/Documents/web-AOT/server/node_modules/redis/index.js:721:21)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (/Users/Documents/web-AOT/server/node_modules/redis/index.js:819:9)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.returnReply (/Users/Documents/web-AOT/server/node_modules/redis/index.js:192:18)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/Users/Documents/web-AOT/server/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:560:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/web-AOT/server/node_modules/redis/index.js:274:27)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
```

Answer (score 3):

[The solution is here](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/1233#issuecomment-362012518)

You have to wrap your object in `JSON.stringify` and then remember to `JSON.parse` the response when you query the key later.

```
// set
client.set(
  "key",
  JSON.stringify(
    {
      example: {
        field: "testing",
        field1: 333
      },
      field: 123
    }, () => {}
  )
);

// get
client.get("key", (err, data) => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to fix the error by making tweaks via the forked library. :)

If anyone ever runs into this error...

https://github.com/rjlee7/connect-redis-crypto